# Can I find 7 groups of 3 numbers such that every pair of numbers 1 to 7 appears once?

Tags: combinatorics, natural-numbers

What I am trying to do is find exactly 7 groups of 3 from {1, 2, 3, ..., 7} that have within them all possible pairs of these numbers.

 For example, {1, 2, 3} has {1, 2}, {2, 3} and {1, 3}
I know there's 21 total pairs from 1 to 7 and 21 pairs generated from the groups of 3 so it **should** be possible but I just can't find the solution.

 (Sorry for the bad formatting and possibly bad tags, I'm a bit new)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

$$ \{1,2,3\}$$
$$ \{1,4,5\}$$
$$ \{1,6,7\}$$
$$ \{2,4,6\}$$
$$ \{2,5,7\}$$
$$ \{3,4,7\}$$
$$ \{3,5,6\}$$

Comment: That was so elegant and a perfect solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: @PedroNyan It is also called the [Fano Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane).